# Changing an element's width with JQuery's addClass

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change an element's width using the addClass function, but it's not working. The element that I try to modify has a width set via an initial class and I try to modify it by adding a new class. The class is added but the property is ignored. Why is that?

Element that I try to modify:

```
<div class="LineOne"></div>
```

Initial CSS:

```
 .LineOne {
    width: 60%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    border-color: #FCFFF5;
    margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
```

JQuery that I use to modify it:

```
$( ".LineOne" ).addClass( "LineOneWidth" );
```

And the respective CSS:

```
.LineOneWidth {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could be because of CSS rule specificity. Now without seeing any relavant  CSS, we can just guessing...

Answer (score 0):

If two classes are trying to set an element's width, the one that is lower in the code will be used. If that's not the case look into CSS specificity or post more information.

In the case of

```
.one {
    width: 100px;
}

.two {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Where both classes are present on an element, said element will have a width of `200px`, however write it like this:

```
div.one {
    width: 100px;
}

.two {
    width: 200px;
}
```

And apply them both to a div, and you'll see that the div will be `100px` wide. This is because the first selector is now more 'specific'. More rules makes it stronger when making decisions which to use.

Comment: That's how I know it, too. However, I seem to be missing something.

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle, to demonstrate the problem? As it stands, it seems to be working fine with your code.

Comment: Yep. it works in JSFiddle, but not in Chrome or FF. https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=piyvGAMEQf

Answer (score -1):

How does your code look like? Maybe syntax is wrong.

```
$('.item').addClass('new-class'); works fine to me.
```